# centralManagerDidUpdateState delegate not getting called

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, bluetooth, communication

I am using CoreBluetooth framework for Bluetooth communication on MAC.

With Pure Objective C the code is working nicely.

I want to call the Objective c code from cpp and I am using a wrapper function to do so and centralManager getting initialized. But centralManagerDidUpdateState delegate is not getting called (i.e. central manager is not powering on).

Are there some things that need to be taken care while handling objective c delegates from cpp class?

I am new to Objective c coding. Any input on this will be helpful.

Code:

CInterface.h->

```
  void wrapperFunction();
```

main.cpp ->

```
#include <CInterface.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    wrapperFunction();
    return a.exec();
}
```

MyDelegateObject.h ->

```
#include <CInterface.h>
#include <IOBluetooth/IOBluetooth.h>

@interface MyDelegateObject : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate> {

}

- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central;
@end
```

MyDelegateObject.mm->

```
@implementation MyDelegateObject

void wrapperFunction(){
    qDebug()<<"Inside Wrapper function";
    MyDelegateObject *myDelegate = [MyDelegateObject alloc];
    CBCentralManager *myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:myDelegate queue:nil]; 
}

- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    qDebug()<<"inside delegate";
}
```

Its enetring into wrapperFunction and I am able to get "Inside Wrapper function" print.
But after initWithDelegate, centralManagerDidUpdateState should get called. this is not happening.

Am i missing something?

Thanks,
SK

Comment: Could you please provide the code ?

Comment: Please note: Im using QT on mac and using IOBluetooth framework.